# Get referer in Blazor server side project

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, blazor-server-side

I'm developing a Blazor server side site for a client and they are using MailChimp for a newsletter signup.  When they fill out a form, there is a confirmation page from MailChimp after which MailChimp redirects them to a page then client specified, in this case /thanks.  However, I only want users to be able to get to this page if they are sent there from MailChimp and not be able to just go directly to that page.

I want to be able to get the referer in the OnInitAsync method and I'd the user was directed there from MailChimp, they would be redirected to the homepage.  I already know how to redirect them, just not get the referring address.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score -2):

You could use HttpRequest.UrlReferrer to check if it came from MailChimp. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer?view=netframework-4.8

```
Uri MyUrl = Request.UrlReferrer;
string host = MyUrl .Host;
```

Or you add a query string parameter like /thanks?r=1234ERTY
if no parameter exists then redirect.